# Minimum dissimilarity between one record and a whole data.frame

Tags: r, similarity

I am trying to make feasible the computation of dissimilarity within records of a massive dataset (600,000 records).

The first task is to compute the dissimilarity using Euclidean Distance between **one single record** and the **whole data.frame** excluding that record.

Considering the following sample:

```
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(5), var2 = rnorm(5), var3 = rnorm(5))
one_row <- mydf[1,]
```

### The question articulates in two steps:

1. use a **vectorized operation** to return a vector of length 4 with the dissimilarity values of `one_row` compared to each row of `mydf[-1,]`
2. from the vector of point 1., extract the index of the row more similar to `one_row`

Then, I could iterate this process for every row in mydf and, therefore, finding for each row its most similar row. This would allow me to perform agglomerative clustering as well as computing statistics criterion like Silhoutte that are based on distance matrix.

#### Update

One possible approach is to replicate one_row to the same size of mydf and vectorize the similarity computation by performing it pair-wise.

```
replicated <- [rep(1, 5), 1:ncol(a)]
```

#### Correct Answer

Both the answers of Jesse Tweedle and won782 are correct to my question.

The positive aspect of Jesse Tweedle's is the possibility of customizing the distance function allowing to use mixed data types. The negative side is that it is not a single expression but it is a pipe of functions.

The positive aspect of won782 is that it is performed in a single expression. The negative aspect is that it only works for matrices, therefore, numeric variables.

I choose won782 answer because his solution can be easily extended to be used as fundamental component for computing Silhouette Criterion without storing the dissimilarity matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to perform rowwise operation for a given vector and compute euclidean distance with every rows.

```
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(5), var2 = rnorm(5), var3 = rnorm(5))
one_row <- mydf[1,]

result = apply(mydf, 1, function(x) {
  sqrt(sum((x - one_row)^2))
})
result
[1] 0.000000 3.333031 3.737814 1.875482 4.216042
```

The result is vector of euclidean distances. Then, you can do `which.min` function to find the index of minimum value.

Using matrix operation :

```
sqrt(rowSums((t(t(as.matrix(mydf)) - as.numeric(one_row)))^2))
```

Benchmark two methods on larger dataset

```
> mydf <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(10000), var2 = rnorm(10000), var3 = rnorm(10000))
> one_row <- mydf[1,]
> # Matrix operation method
> system.time({ 
+   sqrt(rowSums((t(t(as.matrix(mydf)) - as.numeric(one_row)))^2))
+   })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.000   0.000   0.001 
> # Apply Method
> system.time({ 
+   apply(mydf, 1, function(x) {
+     sqrt(sum((x - one_row)^2))
+   })
+ })
   user  system elapsed 
  5.186   0.014   5.204
```

So clearly, matrix operation is faster method.

Comment: Is it possible to vectorize the operation instead of applying a loop? The reason is because to compute the most similar row for each row it would require a non-feasible amount of time. Instead of applying nrow(mydf) vectorized operations, it executes nrow(mydf) apply loop

Comment: The matrix approach is definitely faster. The only negative side is that it cannot be used for mixed data types.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem:

You could use `dist` on `mydf`, but the answer will be too big for your computer (`1e11`-ish elements). So the challenge is to calculate the euclidean distance for each row x the whole dataset. You don't want to replicate the whole thing over and over because you'll be doing it 600,000 times. But you can write a vectorized function to calculate the Euclidean distance, and use `tidyverse` things to apply it succintly.

## Answer:

Write a function `euc` and vectorize it over the second argument.

```
library(tidyverse)
euc <- function(x, y) { 
  sqrt(sum((x - y)^2))
}
euc_ <- Vectorize(euc, vectorize.args = "y")
calculate_distances <- function(row, df) {
  dists <- euc_(row, split(df, 1:nrow(df)))
  # gives you name of row and distance that gives minimum distance.
  dists[dists>0 & dists == min(dists[dists>0])] %>% enframe()
}
```

Then the `calculate_distances` function calculates the euclidean distance from a single row to the rest of the dataset, then collapses the argument down to the name and value of the one with the minimum distance (excluding itself, so we need to include `dist>0`).

Then you combine the vars into one column (which makes it easier to pass to a function like `calculate_distances` without specifying the column names, `var1`, etc). Then use `mutate` and `map` to apply the function to every row, then `unnest` to unpack the results (and keep the original data, if you like).

```
mydf <- data.frame(var1 = rnorm(5), var2 = rnorm(5), var3 = rnorm(5))

mydf %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  group_by(n) %>% 
  nest(var1, var2, var3) %>% 
  mutate(ans = map(data, calculate_distances, df = mydf)) %>%
  unnest(ans, data)
# A tibble: 5 x 6
      n  name    value         var1       var2       var3
  <int> <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1     1     4 1.027080  0.035684445  0.3152272  1.9001506
2     2     5 1.453509 -0.985996620  0.2650241 -0.2146157
3     3     2 1.645737  0.009665813 -0.8393461  0.4907029
4     4     1 1.027080  0.314943627  0.9910671  1.1789382
5     5     2 1.453509  0.436344415  0.5309611 -0.3521368
```

Good luck!  Hope this helps.

Comment: Basically with this step we directly obtain the closest record to each record without storing the whole distance matrix. Furthermore, being a vectorized operation we can quickly compute similarity. Additionally, being calculate_distances a function we can change it for metrics other than Euclidean.